# Server response delays without having provided a time-based blind SQL injection input

Tags: sql-injection

I am new to SQL injection. When I was researching a bug bounty site protected by cloudflare, unsurprisingly, entering `email@gmail.com' OR 1=1--`, to test SQL injection, did not work.

So later, trying to bypass the filter, there came a time when Cloudflare no longer blocked my request, what happened was that the response took about 30 seconds.

This is why I thought it was time-based SQL, but then I realized that the input I provided was not typical for this variant. Usually with a time-based SQL Injection you provide input which would cause the server to delay a period of time before responding if the query is evaluated. For example, with MS SQL server `'WAIT FOR DELAY '0:0:10''` .

That is why I have come to ask you: why might there be a delayed response from the server where my test injection string is designed to trigger a SQL injection but is not deliberately designed to produce an extended delay in the response.

Comment: You do not provide a time-based SQL input. What is "time-based SQL input" mean to you? I think you need to explain the situation better. And I'm not sure that what you've described is any indication of a SQL-based problem, issue, concern, or anything.

Comment: One possibility is that instead of having to return one row, the `OR 1=1` is making it returning the whole table. It depends on the SQL statement that's being executed, but certainly possible.

Comment: I can't answer this as it got closed, but often what I've found with delayed responses to blind SQLi is that the input is breaking the SQL query in some fashion and the application is configured not to provide detailed error logging. The 30 second delay could be a timeout from one of the backend servers. If you want to probe it, string concatenation tests could be useful (so see if te'+'st or te'||'st gets interpreted by the application as "test") as they tend not to cause as many errors.